# Many-to-many joins in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-joins, many-to-many

Just want to know if there is a tool to do a many-to-many join in QGIS?

I have `X` number of polygons that I want to join with a CSV table which contains `Y` number of entries. Essentially I need to have `Y` copies of feature `X1`, `X2`, `...` ending up with `X*Y` features.

For now, I'm using a workaround which is to duplicate the entries in the CSV table `X` times and then do a one-to-many join.

Comment: Have you taken a look at `join attributes by location` and `join vector layers`? If you did, how do they not suit your task?

Comment: The two layers don't have any spatial relationship for the `join attributes by location` to work, and the CSV layer does not have geometry. As I've mentioned, for now I'm using `join attributes by field value`, but I'm limited to a one-to-many join.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get why `one to many` doesn't work. I am under the impression, that you want to add the CSV-attributes to the polygons. Which is `one to many`. Maybe you could add a sketch of your process to clarify things?